# derivative in a vector direction

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces

Could anyone please help me with this question? I'm not sure that I understand how to get the derivative of the direction of a vector.

The derivative of the function $f(x,y) = 2xy^3 – 3x^2y$ at the point $(–1,2)$ in the direction of the vector $v = (1,–1)$ is equal to:

[the answer options are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhSBK.png)

I'm from brazil and not used to math english lol, sorry for any mistake I make when translating.

Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to tell us what you understand, and we may see if you are right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $f(x,y) = 2xy^3 – 3x^2y$

We have $$\nabla f=\nabla (2xy^3 – 3x^2y)=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \hat{i}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \hat{k})(2xy^3 – 3x^2y)= (2y^3-6xy)\hat{i}+ (6xy^2-3x^2)\hat{j}+ 0 \hat{k} $$ 
At $(–1,2)$, $\nabla f =28 \hat{i}-27\hat{j}$

The unit vector in the direction $\vec{v}=(1,-1)$ i.e.,$\vec{v}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}$  is

$\hat{v}=\frac{\hat{i}-\hat{j}}{\sqrt{1+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\hat{i}-\hat{j})$.

Hence the derivative of the given function at $(-1,2) $ and in the direction $\vec{v}=(1,-1)$ is

$\nabla f.\hat{v}= (28 \hat{i}-27\hat{j}).\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\hat{i}-\hat{j}) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (28+27)=\frac{55}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: You are most welcome @Virginia Komar